# Problem getting datum to pass correctly on drag in d3 v7

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Weird issue I'm seeing using drag in d3 v7 (also seeing this with v6). If I define `.call(drag)` such that

```
var drag = d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged )
        .on("end", dragended);
```

and

```
function dragged(event,d) {
  {{things that depend on event and d}}
}
```

then everything works as expected.

However, if I try,

```
var drag = d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", (event,d) => { dragged(event,d) } )
        .on("end", dragended);
```

I get the log yelling at me that `Uncaught TypeError: d is undefined`. What's going on here?

Happy to provide a minimal example tomorrow. Just hoping someone may have seen this before..? I'm fairly new to d3 (and to JS for that matter, ha) and I hope I've got the revised post-v6 syntax right.

**Edit: In my effort to create a minimal example, I realized that the TypeError may have been obfuscating the real issue, which is that `this` isn't being passed correctly.** So strap in.

First, a minimal example that replicates the issue. Modified from [this example](https://observablehq.com/@d3/circle-dragging-i). Not my situation, but same principle. Put this in the body tag:

```
<body>

    <svg></svg>

<script>

function dragstarted(event, d) {
  d3.select(this).raise().attr("stroke", "black");
}

function dragged(event, d) {
    d.x = event.x;
    d.y = event.y;
    d3.select(this).attr("cx", (d) => d.x).attr("cy", (d) => d.y);
}

function dragended(event, d) {
  d3.select(this).attr("stroke", null);
}

var drag = d3.drag()
    .on("start", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", function(event,d) {dragged(event,d)} )
    .on("end", dragended);

var width = 400;
var height = 400;
var radius = 20;

const svg = d3.select("svg")
    .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height])
    .attr("background-color","#ccc")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2);

const circles = d3.range(20).map(i => ({
    x: Math.random() * (width - radius * 2) + radius,
    y: Math.random() * (height - radius * 2) + radius,
    }));

svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(circles)
    .join("circle")
        .attr("cx", d => d.x)
        .attr("cy", d => d.y)
        .attr("r", radius)
        .attr("fill", (d, i) => d3.schemeCategory10[i % 10])
        .call(drag);

</script>

</body>
```

This gives the initial error. `Uncaught TypeError: d is undefined` Replace the `drag` definition with

```
var drag = d3.drag()
    .on("start", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged )
    .on("end", dragended);
```

and it works. Peachy. But if we replace the definition of `dragged` with:

```
function dragged(event, d) {
    d.x = event.x;
    d.y = event.y;
    d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x).attr("cy", d.y);
}
```

We reveal probably the real underlying error: `Uncaught TypeError: this.setAttribute is not a function`. So `this` isn't passing correctly. Same happens if we define:

```
var drag = d3.drag()
    .on("start", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", (event,d) => { dragged(event,d) } )
    .on("end", dragended);
```

I know the arrow notation can lead to some `this` weirdness but at any rate that's not the fix here. If I put the function definition right in the declaration, we get the right `this` and it works again:

```
var drag = d3.drag()
    .on("start", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", function (event,d) { 
        d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x = event.x).attr("cy", d.y = event.y); 
    } )
    .on("end", dragended);
```

Sooo. Why isn't the right `this` getting passed to `dragged()`? And how do I fix it? Even though the above works, it would be a little ugly to do this in my code, and at any rate, I want to understand better how passing attributes works in javascript. Hopefully this contained example helps!

Comment: Your code looks ok. I think a demo would be helpful to dig into the issue.

Comment: @altocumulus Thank you for taking a look. I've added an example!

Comment: That's how JavaScript works. A function can receive more arguments than parameters or less arguments than parameters. In your working case, `.on("drag", dragged )`, that `dragged` function gets passed the event, the datum and `this`. In the non-working case, `.on("drag", function(event,d) {dragged(event,d)})`, the whole anonymous function gets passed the same arguments, but inside it you're passing only two of them as arguments to `dragged`.